# redefinition of basic type when including external library

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, clr

I am writing some code in c++ using Visual Studio 2013 to be referenced from within a .NET application from a CLR class library.  The c++ componenent I am writing the wrapper for is Accusoft ImageGear.  The problem that I am having is that when I include a header file in ImageGear I get the following compile error:

> error C2371: 'AT_HANDLE' : redefinition; different basic
>   types C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\8.1\Include\shared\windef.h  39  1   ImageGearWrapper

I also get the same error reported at lines 73,80,86,93 of windef.h.

I imagine that ImageGear must define a variable called AT_HANDLE, that is also defined in the Windows 8.1 SDK.

What can I do to resolve the conflict?  I have read up on Include Guards, but not sure how to apply them in this case.

I noticed that if I create a Win32 console application, it still gives this error, but if I select "Include MFC" in the project wizard I no longer have the issue.

Comment: Line #39 of windef.h declares the HWND handle type, nothing resembling "AT_HANDLE".  Look for a macro that whack the symbol or an accidental edit of the windef.h file.

Comment: @HansPassant The error also comes up at lines 39, 73, 80, 86, 93.  windef.h has not ever been modified.  The code I am running is pretty basic, and Im not targeting Windows 8, is there a way to just remove the reference to windef.h.